# onscreen gujarati keyboard in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode, c#-3.0

i am creating desktop application like Gujarati To English Dictionary in C#.
For that i need onscreen Gujarati keyboard to display.
How to solve this..?
any help is appreciated.
Thank you all.

Comment: "Desktop Application" == WPF? Or == WinForms? Or == Silverlight?

Comment: its windows Form Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple approach to start with:

1. Create and arange the keyboard buttons on your form
2. Create a TextBox, displaying the user input
3. Add the gujarati letters to the buttons (`Text` property)
4. Create an event handler routine for the click event (see below)
5. Register this routine to the Click event of each of your buttons

Something like this:

```
private TextBox userInputBox;

private void OnButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    userInputBox.Text += button.Text;
}
```

Comment: it means no other third party dll or control is available.is this the only option available?

Comment: @aarti: I don't know a third-party control, but I never tried to find one.